# My car is overheating

Tags: toyota

My 2007 Toyota Camry has been overheating and used an almost full reservoir of coolant within a few hours.   There are no drops or puddles on the ground.  My mechanic says it's a bad radiator.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

If the car is losing coolant, the coolant is either exiting the engine or being consumed internally. If you inspected the engine and the radiator and they are dry (no traces of coolant anywhere on them), most likely the engine is ingesting the coolant. At this point radiator may be good or bad but you have a bigger problem on your hands in that the engine needs an overhaul or replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If your coolant is leaking into your block, you'd see this as a brown/white sludge in your oil filler cap. It's known as emulsification, and is quite common with cars that use a breather pipe and are in a cool/damp climate (my 205 XU engine used to suffer from this).

How much coolant and water does it take to re-fill the system? You might have an air block inside the radiator or one of the coolant hoses. You can check this by squeezing the pipes which go into/out of the radiator, you shouldn't see any bubbles come out of the top of the coolant filler cap.